# Событие change не обрабатывает изменения в input

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Вот пример на plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/w6GzeQapcsIO4vn7ZfC2?p=preview

```
app.directive('initDate', function() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elem) {
      elem.datepicker().on('change', scope.showDate());
    }
  }
})
```

Хочу, чтобы при выборе даты мне выводилось выбранное значение. Но почему-то событие отрабатывает один раз при открытии страницы и больше нет его.

Comment: лучше использовать datepicker написанный на ангуляре чем jquery плагин, тогда и проблем не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчик нужно засунуть ссылку на функцию, а не ее вызов:

`elem.datepicker().on('change', scope.showDate);`